# Who designed/created latex outfits in Star Trek Into Darkness

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-into-darkness, costume

I was wondering who created the latex outfits in the Star Trek into Darkness. Does anyone know?

Comment: IMDb says Michael Kaplan ([link](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1408101/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)). There's [an interview on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6Qq9pJODjA), as well as many more.  This is the first result on Google, did I understand you wrong (you meant someone else) or something?

Comment: You might also have better luck with answers if this question was posted on the [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) Stack. Here we mostly ask questions about in universe content; not that you won't get any information at all, but there are guidelines we try to follow between the sites.

Comment: @Odin1806 this question is still on-topic for this site; but, cross-posting to M&TV (while keeping the SFF question up) is against network policy. In any case, Lisa, please clarify (with an [edit]) whether you meant Kaplan or someone else, as, if it's really about Kaplan, this question will likely attract downvotes for "no research".